# App freezes on black screen after migrating project to Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a project developed on Swift 3.0. It uses CocoaPods as the dependency manager. Today I finally got some time to migrate it to Swift 4.2 using these steps:

1. Updated all pods to the latest version available
2. Fixed all errors
3. Migrated the project to Swift 4.2
4. Fixed all warnings

But now the project doesn't run anymore. Actually, it runs, but all I have is a black screen on the Simulator, the app doesn't even shows the launch screen. I've put a breakpoint on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but it is not executed. The output in the Debug Area doesn't show any errors or exceptions.

Is there something I can do to find out what's going on? Or should I use another strategy to migrate this project to Swift 4.2?

Comment: Might be worth rewriting the AppDelegate methods and letting XCode autocomplete. I think there were some changes between 3 and 4.

Comment: @Magnas thanks! The problem was with `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, which was `private` before.

Answer (score 0):

**Please update `AppDelegate` method**

```
application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```

**replace by**

```
application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool
```